# Switching from ActionScript to JavaScript, tips for writing code?

Tags: javascript, programming-practices, coding-style

I am quite comfortable with using actionscript3 and flash. I also have some experience with Java. But recently, I started learning JavaScript and node.js. I ultimately want to make a 3d game in threejs, but for now I simply want to make a chat application.

I want to get into the habit of using JavaScript. Unfortunately, I am finding it very difficult to start using JavaScript. The difficulties I am facing are

- No suggestions for different methods and properties pop up, like they do in the Eclipse IDE and Flash Builder IDE. Like when you press dot after object, it shows all the methods and properties relating to that object and it becomes really easy to see what the parameters are and needed to be passed and stuff.
- How to organize code? In ActionScript3, I could simply make different classes in different packages. I could then import and use those classes in one main file. How does it work in JavaScript?
- Functions. I have seen people use anonymous functions in javascript. But I am compelled to write external functions as I am in the habit of it. What is better in JavaScript workflow? What do you advice?
- How is code executed within a HTML file? So if I have several `<script></script>` tags and I declare a variable in one of them, can the tags below it and above it access that variable?

Comment: It looks like you want to read an introduction on javascript.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Alright, I guess it is w3school for me then.

Comment: MDN is probably a better idea.

Comment: What OS do you use for development?

Comment: @JBRWilkinson My OS is Windows 7. Do you know of any free Javascript and Node.js IDEs

Comment: Try out webstorm http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

Comment: @marko, unfortunately it is not free of cost, so it does not suit me. I heard about eclipse plugins but can not find any? Can somebody give me a link to a good one?

Comment: You need to pick up "JavaScript: the Good Parts" by Douglas Crockford.

Comment: **Please, please, please, forget about w3school**. That place is full of bad code, worst-practises and outdated information. Go for Douglas Crockfords book, also John Resig's, and use Mozilla Developer Network as reference for any syntactic/compatibility reference.

Comment: Okay. Two things. W3Schools is often dated/incomplete but it's not the antichrist. Crockford however, often is the antichrist. (kidding, but numerous positive contributions aside, he does often confuse personal style preference for general best practices which leads to a lot of rookies with annoying ideas about things that should never ever be done who can't tell you why)

Comment: did you check **['javascript' tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)** at Stack Overflow? Their "Learning JavaScript" section looks quite impressive. And "Wisdom from the Stack" section... And "Frequently Asked Questions" section... and, well, everything I see there

Comment: [Regarding why w3scool is usually inaccurate](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: When I first saw it W3Schools was scarily inaccurate, but nowadays it seems better. I'm still alarmed at the people who go there for SQL reference when SQLite.org has grammar diagrams and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Autocompletion

Javascript is a dynamic language and it's impossible to get anywhere near to what you have in Actionscript or Java. Just accept what your IDE (WebStorm for instance) might suggest for you. This goes for any interpreted language really.

> How to organize code?

Have a look at [requirejs](http://requirejs.org) or node.js's own [module](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) [require](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/what-is-require) function.

> Anonymous functions.

Yes, get use to them. Javascript is very much function-based so you'd just have to accept that part. [Here](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html) is a great starting point.

> Several  tags and I declare a variable in one of them,
>   can the tags below it and above it access that variable?

Nope, only tags below it. Try this:

```
<body>
   <script> console.log(x); </script>
   <script> var x = 1; </script>
</body>
```

Console prints "x is undefined".

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to check out [Haxe](http://haxe.org/). You should use the stable version (2.10) for now, as version 3 is only in RC stage and many IDEs and 3rd party libraries do not yet have full support.

Haxe should be fairly familiar to you as an ActionScript developer. The way you would write an application would be to create markup and then query for the nodes you wish to add dynamic behavior to and manipulate them.

As for IDEs, the website contains a [comprehensive list](http://haxe.org/com/ide). If you're on windows, then you definitely will want to use FlashDevelop. It has a project template for haxe/js to get you started.

You might also be interested to have a look at [NME](http://www.haxenme.org/), an ambitious project now backed by BlackBerry, that lets you use the Flash Player API on about every platform.

I suggest you join the [Google Group or the IRC channel](http://haxe.org/com) if you have any problems. The community is very active and friendly.

---

I should point out, there's a whole number of alternatives that you might want to consider (they all have some basic resemblance to AS3):

- [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/)
- [Dart](http://www.dartlang.org/)
- [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/)
- [ScriptSharp](http://scriptsharp.com/)

Personally, I favor Haxe over all of them, because it is both richer in features and not limited to JavaScript, but your needs may be different.

Comment: Not to disrespect your effort for answering me, but I do not want to use frameworks and external libraries, instead I want to understand how to use the naked JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

> No suggestions for different methods and properties pop up, like they do in the Eclipse IDE and Flash Builder IDE. Like when you press dot after object, it shows all the methods and properties relating to that object and it becomes really easy to see what the parameters are and needed to be passed and stuff.

This isn't really my cup of tea, but I'm sure there are Eclipse plugins that can do this to some extent for JavaScript. Due to the nature of functions and the object model in JavaScript, it would be much harder to do this for all cases than a language like Java.

> How to organize code? In ActionScript3, I could simply make different classes in different packages. I could then import and use those classes in one main file. How does it work in JavaScript?

Check out [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). As far as I know, it's the most commonly accepted method for formatting JavaScript "modules" (which are a JavaScript idiom).

> Functions. I have seen people use anonymous functions in javascript. But I am compelled to write external functions as I am in the habit of it. What is better in JavaScript workflow? What do you advice?

You can write a lot of JavaScript without *having* to resort to anonymous functions, but anonymous functions make it easier. I think this is something that you can learn in time.

> How is code executed within a HTML file? So if I have several  tags and I declare a variable in one of them, can the tags below it and above it access that variable?

The tags *below* it will have access to that variable. Code is executed linearly, and JavaScript's scoping is simple, limited, and oft criticized (but efficient if you know the caveats).

Answer (score 0):

For IDE:s consider using something that has good autocomplete support like visual studio, aptana or webstorm. These will make your life a lot easier.

For class-like structures consider Module pattern.

http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth

Check out Douglas Crockfords book good parts
and maybe check out some book on javascript patterns.

Because there aren't any classes don't mean that there aren't any good 
solutions to organising code.

Comment: Thanks for the good links. Douglas Crockford's book seems to be a good suggestion for me. But do you know of any free IDEs or eclipse plugins.

Comment: Use visual web developer express. It's free! http://www.asp.net/downloads Or aptana - it's free! http://aptana.org/. Even netbeans is a good alternative! http://netbeans.org/ And it's free too! Or notepad++ http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.3.html Even flashdevelop would work http://www.flashdevelop.org/